# React Button Click Event Not working correctly

Tags: reactjs

How come the following React Button Emitter is not working? It should display the word Apple, with button click.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick('apple')}>
        Test Button
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

function handleClick(props) {
  console.log(props)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for it to get called on click you need to pass a function. Right now your code is *invoking* the function:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* Creates an anonymous function that calls `handleClick` */}
      <button onClick={() => { handleClick('apple'); }}>
        Test Button
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By doing onClick={handleClick('apple')} what you are doint is to put the result of handleClick('apple') at rendering time, not onClick time.

onClick={() => handleClick('apple')} will work because you are creating a function and assign it to onClick, without executing it yet.

This is how React works, because what you are writing is actually just javascript (not html, even if it looks like so).

Your way would instead be perfectly ok if you were using Vue, for example, because in that case you are working in an html template (unless you don't want to use jsx..)